# how can I out a parameter as varchar2 in oracle

Tags: c#, oracle, plsql

I am using oracle 10g

this is my package specification and body

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE P_1 AS
    TYPE T_CURSOR IS REF CURSOR;
    PROCEDURE USP_1(SP_NUM OUT VARCHAR2);
END P_1;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY P_1 AS
    PROCEDURE USP_1(SP_NUM OUT VARCHAR2) IS
    BEGIN
        SELECT to_char(concat(to_char(sysdate, 'yyyymm'),
                              to_char("ActionId".nextval, '000')))
            INTO SP_NUM FROM dual;
    END USP_1;
END P_1;
```

my back-end code is

```
using (OracleConnection oracleConnection = new BaseRepository().Connection)
{
    oracleConnection.Open();

    OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand("P_1.USP_1", oracleConnection);

    command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.Parameters.Add("SP_NUM", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 50,
                           System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output);

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();  // exception arises at this line

    var Number = Convert.ToInt32(command.Parameters["SP_REQ_NUM"].Value.ToString());
```

this is the exception i am getting.

```
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
```

I don't know where i am doing something wrong.

Comment: Does testing this in a pl/sql debugger outputs the same error or just your C#(? I think) code? because I think this is a C# problem, and not your plsql

Comment: pl/sql debugger shows the exact result with no errors. but still i think the problem is with out varchar2 in oracle. I haven't done with a single parameter out as varchar2 before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no less than 10 overloads of the [`OracleParameterCollection.Add`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/win.111/b28375/OracleParameterCollectionClass.htm#i1013260) method.  It looks like you have accidentally called the wrong one.

I believe the one you want is [`Add(string, OracleDbType, int, object, ParameterDirection)`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/win.111/b28375/OracleParameterCollectionClass.htm#i1013550), in which case you're just missing a value for the `object` parameter.  This parameter should contain an initial value for the Oracle parameter you're using.  In your case, however, the initial value doesn't matter as it's an `out` parameter.  Add `null` after `50` and your stored procedure call should succeed.

The one you have called is [`Add(string, OracleDbType, object, ParameterDirection)`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/win.111/b28375/OracleParameterCollectionClass.htm#i1013496).  The size `50` has been interpreted as an initial value for the parameter.  I'm not sure how to interpret the error that Oracle returns ("numeric or value error") – that implies to me that Oracle has tried to convert a string to a number and failed.  Perhaps the value `50` overrides the type `OracleDbType.Varchar2` and so Oracle expects a number rather than a string?

There were another couple of problems I found:

- Should `command.Parameters["SP_REQ_NUM"]` be `command.Parameters["SP_NUM"]`?
- Your stored procedure doesn't return a number; calling `Convert.ToInt32` on a string such as `201405 001` will fail.

Comment: FYI. code doesn't get to the two line you mentioned as additional problems. Before executing the additional error lines, it catches the exception. and on the other hand, Add methods are truly not less than 10 but let me tell you short way of using your desired method, "You just give the right parameters to the method and it will automatically call the desired one".

Comment: @KhurramZulfiqarAli: glad to have helped.  I found the other two problems once I got the stored procedure call working.  Clearly you'd never get to them if the stored procedure call fails.