# .Net calling Oracle Array bound stored procedure output VarChar2

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, stored-procedures

I'm calling an Oracle array bound stored procedure from C#
I can add output parameters of type NUMBER, and the return values are correctly populated.

If I try to use output values of type VARCHAR2, I'm getting "OracleParameter.ArrayBindSize is invalid" Exception.

This works:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CLOUDDBA.INSERTTEST (

    P_VALUE NUMBER, 
    P_CODE  OUT NUMBER--,
 --   P_MESSAGE OUT VARCHAR
)
AS
BEGIN 
        P_CODE := P_Value ;
        --P_MESSAGE := '';

    IF P_Value = 1 THEN
        P_CODE := 1;
        --P_MESSAGE := 'ONE';
    END IF;


END INSERTTEST;
```

C# code:

```
        var values = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };

        ocmd.CommandText = "INSERTTEST";

        ocmd.CommandType = CommandType;
        ocmd.BindByName = true;
        ocmd.ArrayBindCount = 3;

        ocmd.Transaction = transaction;
        ocmd.Parameters.Clear();

        var pValue = new OracleParameter("P_VALUE", OracleDbType.Int32, 255, ParameterDirection.Output) { Value = values };
        ocmd.Parameters.Add(pValue);

        var pVCode= new OracleParameter("P_CODE", OracleDbType.Int32, 255, ParameterDirection.Output);
        ocmd.Parameters.Add(pVCode);
```

This blows up:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CLOUDDBA.INSERTTEST (

    P_VALUE NUMBER, 
    P_CODE  OUT NUMBER,
    P_MESSAGE OUT VARCHAR
)

AS

BEGIN 
        P_CODE := P_Value ;
        P_MESSAGE := '';

    IF P_Value = 1 THEN
        P_CODE := 1;
        P_MESSAGE := 'ONE';
    END IF;


END INSERTTEST;
```

C# code:

```
        var values = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };

        ocmd.CommandText = "INSERTTEST";

        ocmd.CommandType = CommandType;
        ocmd.BindByName = true;
        ocmd.ArrayBindCount = 3;

        ocmd.Transaction = transaction;
        ocmd.Parameters.Clear();

        var pValue = new OracleParameter("P_VALUE", OracleDbType.Int32, 255, ParameterDirection.Output) { Value = values };
        ocmd.Parameters.Add(pValue);

        var pVCode= new OracleParameter("P_CODE", OracleDbType.Int32, 255, ParameterDirection.Output);
        ocmd.Parameters.Add(pVCode);

        var pVMessage= new OracleParameter("P_MESSAGE", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 255, ParameterDirection.Output);
        ocmd.Parameters.Add(pVMessage);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how can I out a parameter as varchar2 in oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23866998/how-can-i-out-a-parameter-as-varchar2-in-oracle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.

<strike>Use SQL Server.</strike>

Need to specify ArrayBindSize.

replace

```
var pVMessage = new OracleParameter("P_MESSAGE", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 255, ParameterDirection.Output);
```

with

```
var pVMessage = new OracleParameter("P_MESSAGE", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 255, ParameterDirection.Output) {ArrayBindSize = new int[]{255, 255, 255}};
```